# Avoiding long look up paths for variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a closure for dereferencing variables useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288664/is-a-closure-for-dereferencing-variables-useful)

I've come across an information that because of the way that variable look up works in JavaScript i can gain a performance increase in some situations if i copy the variable i'd otherwise have to look up in a scope chain to a local variable for further access. Are there any general guidelines for this? Creating variables costs too. Is there a way to benchmark access times?

I'm not this paranoid about performance, but i like to stay aware of these things.

Comment: Typically storing a reference/copy results in a performance gain over long lookup paths, although recent browsers have been working on many under the cover optimizations. For benchmarking you can check out : http://benchmarkjs.com/

Comment: Well i at least hope this question can help people find the duplicate, because i'd never figure to search for that.