# Why is this javascript necessary?

Tags: javascript

I was reading the source code for [pallet.js](https://github.com/google/palette.js/blob/master/palette.js#L84) and came across this.

```
var ret = (function(proto) {
  return {
    slice: function(arr, opt_begin, opt_end) {
      return proto.slice.apply(arr, proto.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    },
    extend: function(arr, arr2) {
      proto.push.apply(arr, arr2);
    }
  };
})(Array.prototype);
var slice = ret.slice;
var extend = ret.extend;
```

Why is this necessary? Why could they not simply write this:

```
var slice = function(arr,opt_begin,opt_end) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.apply(arr,[opt_begin,opt_end]));
}
var extend = function(arr,arr2) {
  return Array.prototype.push.apply(arr,arr2);
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

In response to the duplicate question. I don't think it is a duplicate, but that question definitely does address my question. So it is an optimization. But won't each one only be evaluated once? So is there really a significant improvement here for two function calls?

Also if we are worried about performance why are we calling `proto.slice.call(arguments,1)` instead of constructing the array of two elements by hand `[opt_begin,opt_end]`, is slice faster?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a closure for dereferencing variables useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288664/is-a-closure-for-dereferencing-variables-useful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure what was the original rationale behind that code (only the author knows) but I can see a few differences:

- `proto` is a closed-over local variable, while instead `Array` is a global. It's possible for a smart enough Javascript engine to optimize access because `proto` is never changed and thus it could even be captured by value, not reference. `proto.slice` can be faster than `Array.prototype.slice` because one lookup less is needed.
- passing `opt_begin` and `opt_end` as `undefined` is not the same as not passing them in general. The called function can know if a parameter was passed and happens to be `undefined` or if instead it wasn't passed. Using `proto.slice.call(arguments, 1)` ensures that the parameters are passed to `slice` only if they were actually passed to the closure.

Comment: AH! Calling slice instead of defining it yourself now makes perfect sense.

But `Array.prototype.slice` vs `proto.slice` saves one lookup (not sure if that is the right word) total since we had to pass `Array.prototype` as a parameter first. We then call `ret.slice` and `ret.extend` which themselves are two lookups... So wouldn't this code run slower?

Comment: The lookup to create the closure is done only once. In your example instead it's done every time the function is called.

Comment: Final question... Is there anything wrong with my logic in this test if we make proto a local variable?
http://jsperf.com/palette-js-perf-test

Comment: @Crackers: seems to me you're measuring the time for creating the wrappers (something that is done only once), not the time to actually call them.

Comment: you are entirely correct. I updated the tests. It shows no major difference in the performance of either on my browser. http://jsperf.com/palette-js-perf-test

Answer (score 3):

Because the syntax is just so much cooler. Plus you can rationalize it's use by telling yourself that it's more DRY. You didn't have to type `Array.prototype` twice.

Comment: It won't save you a property lookup either as the closure will add 1 property lookup anyway.